# cant send parameters to webservice in python

Tags: python, web-services

Im trying to send paramteres to .net webservices. but wrong response returns.I sent "1" value for all parametres.

but the response is according to "0" parameters.

Do u have any solutions about this.

```
 from SOAPpy import WSDL
    import SOAPpy
    from SOAPpy import structType
    from SOAPpy import SOAPProxy
    import os, sys
    import urllib2
    wsdlUrl = 'http://****/Service1.asmx?wsdl';

    #namespace ="http://tempuri.org/"

    testSuiteId = 1
    operationsTypeId = 1
    #SOAPpy.Config.debug=1
    ##print(type(testSuiteId))
    ##print(type(operationsTypeId))




    dbfetchSrv = WSDL.Proxy(wsdlUrl)

    print("***"*30)
    #print dbfetchSrv
    result = []

    **result = dbfetchSrv.FetchTestCase(testSuiteId,operationsTypeId)**
    print("-"*30)
    #print result
    print("-"*30)

    for i in result:
          print i
```

Result is :

```
<SOAPpy.Types.structType OperationData at 70221480>: {'retryCount': '0', 'opId': '0', 'productId': '0'}
```

Comment: any ideas? Im in trouble..

Answer (score 0):

Dont know how your wsdl looks like, but maybe testSuiteId and operationsTypeId must be strings not int?

Comment: I checked this.
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/FetchTestCase"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <FetchTestCase xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <testSuiteId>int</testSuiteId>
      <operationsTypeId>int</operationsTypeId>
    </FetchTestCase>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>